# Does Python itself break inheritance foundations with Hashable class?

Tags: python, inheritance, hashable

```py
from collections import Hashable

issubclass(list, object)      # True
issubclass(object, Hashable)  # True
issubclass(list, Hashable)    # False
```

I thought that inheritance was a transitive relationship. So if "A inherits from B" and "B inherits from C" then "A inherits from C".

How come lists are not hashable considering that objects carry **hash** among their attribute?

Comment: `Hashable` isn't a true class, actually. In the sense that neither `object` or `list` actually inherit from `Hashable`

Comment: so, reading the original [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/) that introduced abc's is informative